# Predict the value based on two parameters

Tags: machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression

I am trying to learn numerical analysis. I am following this articles - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_iris_logistic.html

My data looks like this :

```
date    hr_of_day   vals
2014-05-01  0   72
2014-05-01  1   127
2014-05-01  2   277
2014-05-01  3   411
2014-05-01  4   666
2014-05-01  5   912
2014-05-01  6   1164
2014-05-01  7   1119
2014-05-01  8   951
2014-05-01  9   929
2014-05-01  10  942
2014-05-01  11  968
2014-05-01  12  856
2014-05-01  13  835
2014-05-01  14  885
2014-05-01  15  945
2014-05-01  16  924
2014-05-01  17  914
2014-05-01  18  744
2014-05-01  19  377
2014-05-01  20  219
2014-05-01  21  106
2014-05-01  22  56
2014-05-01  23  43
2014-05-02  0   61
```

For given date and and hr, I want to predict the `vals` and identify pattern.

I have written this code :

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# read the data in
Train = pd.read_csv("data_scientist_assignment.tsv")
#print df.head()
x1=["date", "hr_of_day", "vals"]
#print x1
#print df[x1]
test=pd.read_csv("test.tsv")


model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(Train[x1], Train["vals"])
print(model)
print model.score(Train[x1], Train["vals"])

print model.predict_proba(test[x1])
```

I am getting thsi error:

```
KeyError: "['date' 'hr_of_day' 'vals'] not in index"
```

What is the issue. Is there any better way to do this?

test file format:

```
date    hr_of_day
2014-05-01  0
2014-05-01  1
2014-05-01  2
2014-05-01  3
2014-05-01  4
2014-05-01  5
2014-05-01  6
2014-05-01  7
```

Full error stake:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socratis.py", line 16, in <module>
    model.fit(Train[x1], Train["vals"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1986, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2030, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.ix._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1210, in _convert_to_indexer
    raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: "['date' 'hr_of_day' 'vals'] not in index"
```

Comment: @Merlin, this question contains code and is about a programming error, not about statistics itself. IMO, it's perfectly on-topic here on SO.

Comment: Please include the full error stacktrace and not only the error name, though.

Comment: @cel:updated it

Answer (score 1):

I suggest providing [`sep='\t'` parameter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) when reading TSV:

```
Train = pd.read_csv("data_scientist_assignment.tsv", sep='\t') # use TAB as column separator
```

When you fix this, there is another problem in the queue: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2014-09-13'`
This is because linear regression wants numeric features and column `date` is a string type.

You can introduce new column `timestamp` by converting the date to timestamp (seconds since epoch) and use it as a feature:

```
Train['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Train['date']).apply(lambda a: a.timestamp())
x1=["timestamp", "hr_of_day", "vals"]
```

From a ML perspective, you shouldn't use your target value `vals` as an input feature. You should also consider representing the date as individual features: day, mont, year; or day-of-week, it depends on what you want to model.

Comment: still get same error after ommiting vals in x1. Is the test file format is correct?

Comment: @user3449212 try adding also `sep='\t'` argument for the `read_csv`. Before doing anything further, make sure you have properly loaded the TSV file. `print(Train.columns)` and `print(Train)` etc.

Comment: Including vals in X and both Y means you want to predict _vals_ using _vals_ which makes no sense. But from programming perspective it doesn't matter, it shouldnt produce any error.

Comment: thanks, I updated the code. print looks like `Index([u'2014-05-01', u'0', u'72'], dtype='object')
Index([u'date', u'hr_of_day'], dtype='object')
` but index error still persist

Comment: Its hard to see your problem, but the first print should do sth like `Index([u'date', u'hr_of_day, u'vals'], dtype='object')`, meaning column names. Try juggling with the parameters while looking at the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: here is the data file - I appreciate if you can try this code- https://gist.github.com/anonymous/980fbcca45795641ecfa8567fba9c21c

Comment: @user3449212 I have rewriten the answer to solve the actual problem: when loading TSV, you have to tell the parser to use TAB as separator

Comment: Thakns a lot, but still I am getting some error - 'Traceback
    Train['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Train['date']).apply(lambda a: a.timestamp())
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/cor0e/series.py", line 2220, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/src/inference.pyx", line 1088, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/li.c:62658)
  File "tis.py", line 11 <lambda>
    Train['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Train['date']).apply(lambda a: a.timestamp())
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'timestamp'